# Sort values by columns and not rows

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I hope you can help me with this stupid problem.

I need to sort my columns by highest values. My dataframe consist of 31 columns, with the first 7 looking like this.

[image]

I need to look like this

[image]

I have tried with this code

```
sorted_df = df_1.sort_values(df_1.last_valid_index(), axis=1)
```

But it wont work. Basically, out of all the columns, I need to find the 6 column with highest values. Can you help me out ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can transpose, sort and transpose back

```
df = pd.DataFrame( { "name": ["messi"], "height": [170], "weight":[72], "attack_cross":[88] })

df.T[df.T.index != 'name'].sort_values(0,ascending = False).T
```

gives

```
        height  attack_cross    weight
0       170     88              72
```

add back player name and you are good.

If you only want the top 6, you can add in `head(6)`

```
df.T[df.T.index != 'name'].sort_values(0,ascending = False).head(6).T
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the way you do it. Wont I have to write in all the 31 columns, you do in the first line ?

Comment: No, that  was just to create an example DataFrame to show the code.  You only need the second line as i assume you already have a dataframe.