# Pythonic way to find out the smallest 2D plane(box) to fit all pieces(biggest ones)

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Im getting csv file with many pieces with length/width dimensions and need to find out the smallest box l/w. First thoughts was to transpose(sort) between pandas df columns([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59628607/sort-values-by-columns-and-not-rows)) to collect the biggest value of both in first column, so this biggest value would be one side of box and the biggest of second column would be another side of box:

| length | width |
| --- | --- |
| 200 | 150 |
| 100 | 300 |

transpose to this

| length | width |
| --- | --- |
| 300 | 100 |
| 200 | 150 |

So box would be 300x150.
But Im getting error for example where I linked above. Also it possible to sort in nested list in same way. So questions:

1. What is the best way(pythonic) to store(manipulate) data of 2(3) dimensions l/w(thickness).
2. Pretty sure there will be more elegant way to solve this, so please show examples or link where I could read because dont know how to search correctly.
3. How sort values in pandas between same row but different columns. Thx.

Comment: Sounds like a 2D bin packing problem.

Comment: 2D bin packing assumes that u have box size. I need to get it from sizes in list.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question: if you're looking for the minimum length and minimum width, why not just take the minimum of each column? See for instance https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html

Comment: I need smallest one to fit all, I wanna just put all pieces one by one(sandwich) to box, but size of box determines the biggest two pieces. For example I have box 1000x500 and pieces 300x600, 100x450, 350x500 how to check will it fit or not? if put it in that direction it wont fit.  So firstly Im rotating all pieces by longest side: 600x300, 450x100, 500x350 and now you see, that box must be at least 600 length (biggest L value) and 350 (biggest W value) so all other pieces gonna fit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge your columns as a sorted tuple and sort values at the end:

```
cols = ['length', 'width']
f = lambda x: sorted(tuple(x), reverse=True)
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(f, axis=1, result_type='expand')
df = df.sort_values(cols)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   length  width
0     200    150
1     300    100
```

Comment: Thx 4 reply. It works. What to change to leave indexing ascending and sort only horizontally (between columns)?

Comment: First answer was good, it just to get deeper understanding. U now reindexed, but how to leave original index but sort between columns to get: 0: 200 150; 1: 300 100.

Comment: Also if can please help on other question, just dont wanna make another topic. After this Im calculating area (m^2). Example: I have 20 pieces in list, first 8 pieces = 9.8m2,  so I need sum column until get sum <= 10, then split df with left pieces to determine again size of box. Just my boxes cannot fit  > 10m2. Thx, buddy.

Comment: Remove the `ascending=False` parameter. For your other question, I understand you don't want to open a new topic but the problem it's not trivial (code) so I can't answer here.

Comment: Remove `ascending=False` just sort values in descending, but not leaves original indexes ascending. I have created another topic about sum: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69130536/pandas-sum-column-until-sumvalues-then-split-left-df-items-to-dfnew/69130722#69130722). I have got an answer but if u wanna show ur method you r welcome :)

Comment: @Justme4ever. Please post what you expect with index and values. I don't get it for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy to sort and make a new dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
pd.DataFrame(np.sort(np.sort(df.values, axis=1)[:, ::-1], axis=0),
             columns=df.columns)
```

output:

```
   length  width
1     300    100
0     200    150
```

You can also use:

```
(df.apply(sorted,
          reverse=True,
          axis=1,
          result_type='expand')
   .rename(columns=dict(zip(range(len(df.columns)), df.columns)))
   .sort_values(cols, ascending=False) # optional if the goal is to get the max per column
)
```

output:

```
   length  width
1     300    100
0     200    150
```

Comment: Yes, but 1- this is trivial, 2- if the goal is to take the max per column, this is useless

Comment: If it makes you happy, I gladly do it @Corralien ;) anyway, I added a better answer I think

Comment: Thx for reply. I have a lot of columns with different datatype and Im getting error: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str' . How to specify which columns I wanna sort? I have tried to specify but it wont help. sorted = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(np.sort(dfRaw[['actualHeight', 'actualWidth']].values, axis=1)[:, ::-1], axis=0),
                      columns=dfRaw[['actualHeight', 'actualWidth']])

Comment: @Justme4ever this means you probably have incorrect types in your data, you should try to convert to int. Can you provide your data as dictionary? Use `your_dataframe.to_dict()` and paste the content in your question.

Comment: Ur sorting based on all columns, if df of 2 columns with int or float I think it will work, but how specify in ur example exactly columns which I wanna sort? Because I have other columns like orderName, pieceName and etc.. I havent deep knowledge but see there problem "columns=df.columns" and/or 'df.values', u r not specifying which columns to sort.

Comment: @Justme4ever Well of course, if you have other columns you need to subset them and leave the rest alone, this was however not in your question ;) You can add `[['length', 'width']]` before the `.apply` for this effect.

Comment: Yea, maybe my bad, but Im asking only specific things which I dont understand without not necessarily info and maybe u dont have to stick so narrowly. ty for help:)