# Pandas sum column until >= sum(values) then split left df items to dfNEW

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have df with mixed datatypes, example:

df:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1st | 1 |
| 2nd | 5 |
| 3rd | 3.5 |
| 4th | 8 |

when df['value'].sum() >= 10 split to dfNew (sum of first 3 = 9.5 so need to split left items to dfNew, in my example need split last row)

dfNew:

| name | value |
| --- | --- |
| 4st | 8 |

P.s. I assume I can done it by iterating(itertuples/iteritems) & sum(items) then get indexes and split but what are 'more pandas' way done this?

Comment: Do you want to split once or multiple times? If multiple times, does the cumulative sum should be reset to 0 before finding the next split?

Comment: Hey, buddy. I need to split as much as possible depending of values count. I haventr tried ur example yet, gonna try later. So if it splits not only once, so everything is perfect :).

Answer (score 0):

use `cumsum` and then do the `binning` and then do the `groupby` in binning for example:

```
df['cumsum_val'] = df['value'].cumsum()
```

`binning = list(range(0, math.ceil(df['cumsum_val'].iloc[-1]) + 10), 10) # here you are checking with every 10 (addition of the latest`)

```
df['binning'] = pd.cut(df['cumsum_val'], bins= binning)
```

after this, you can do the groupby in binnings:

```
grouped_df = df.groupby('binning')
```

finally get the splitted df_lists

```
df_new_lists = [grouped_df.get_group(x) for x in grouped_df.groups]
```

`df_new_lists` is the lists of the dataframe

Comment: Did you try your code? I see several errors that would prevent it from running.

Comment: @Stef, hmm, what type of errors, there could have been typos, but the implementation should work (at least I saw one typos in cumsum_val and fixed. ).

Comment: Most obvious are a missing `'` and trying to get a `range` with floating-point values.

Comment: I am going to delete my answer, because using `pandas.cut` as you suggest is much better than what I was doing. However, in the meantime I have edited it to use `pandas.cut`; and as you can see we have to be very careful with the end-value of the range, otherwise the last element might get "NaN" instead of a bin.

Comment: @Stef, yeap thats why in edited answer. I have used math.ceiling and then adding +10 offset and do the binning after that.  Otherwise, the last point will get left out because the binning will turn it to Nan as there is no range in binning that defines the last point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of:

- [`.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to get the cumulative sums;
- [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to compare the cumulative sums with your threshold;
- [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group rows that received the same result.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th', '6th', '7th'], 'value': [1,5,3.5,8,2,9,2]})
threshold = 10

df['cumsums'] = df['value'].cumsum()

bins = range(0, int(df['cumsums'].iloc[-1]+threshold+1), threshold)
df['groups'] = pd.cut(df['cumsums'], bins=bins)

df_list = [pd.DataFrame(g) for _,g in df.groupby('groups')]

print(df)
#   name  value  cumsums    groups
# 0  1st    1.0      1.0   (0, 10]
# 1  2nd    5.0      6.0   (0, 10]
# 2  3rd    3.5      9.5   (0, 10]
# 3  4th    8.0     17.5  (10, 20]
# 4  5th    2.0     19.5  (10, 20]
# 5  6th    9.0     28.5  (20, 30]
# 6  7th    2.0     30.5  (30, 40]

print(df_list)
# [
#   name  value  cumsums   groups
# 0  1st    1.0      1.0  (0, 10]
# 1  2nd    5.0      6.0  (0, 10]
# 2  3rd    3.5      9.5  (0, 10],
#   name  value  cumsums    groups
# 3  4th    8.0     17.5  (10, 20]
# 4  5th    2.0     19.5  (10, 20],
#   name  value  cumsums    groups
# 5  6th    9.0     28.5  (20, 30]
#   name  value  cumsums    groups
# 6  7th    2.0     30.5  (30, 40]
# ]
```

Note that this code assumes that values are nonnegative, so that the cumsums are positive and increasing. If that is not the case, then you must use a more robust definition for `bins`, such as:

```py
bins = range(int(min(df['cumsums'])), int(max(df['cumsums']))+threshold+1, threshold)
```

Comment: Hey. Thx for reply, Im gonna try later, but I can have items 100+ and  sum 80+, so I need split all by <=10.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cumsum` and `idxmax` then slice the dataframe ([idx:])

```
dfNew = df.iloc[df['value'].cumsum().ge(10).idxmax():]
```

Output

```
>>> dfNew
  name  value
3  4th    8.0
```